# Escaped HTML in XML node via XSLT into XSL-FO

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xalan, apache-fop

I have a document that has to be generated as PDF. I use Xalan and Apache FOP for processing an XML with XSLT into XSL-FO.

In my XML tree there is a node like this:

```
<root>
    <formula>
        <text>3+10*10^-6*l</text>
        <html>&lt;html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"&gt;3 &middot; + 10 &middot; 10&lt;sup&gt;-6&lt;/sup&gt; · &lt;i&gt;l&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</html>
    </formula>     
</root>
```

How can I not only get proper HTML (by using `disable-output-escaping="yes"`) but also get a node-set (`exsl:node-set`?) that I can process later on? I mean, I want to get a XSL-FO representation of that HTML formula in order to integrate that into my PDF output.

Something like

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:b">
    <fo:inline font-weight="bold"><xsl:apply-templates/></fo:inline>
</xsl:template>
```

There may be a solution using `saxon:parse()`. However, I cannot switch to that from Xalan-J.

Is there a solution in my scenario?

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly write one stylesheet to process with Xalan that does

```
<xsl:template match="html">
  <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>
```

which then creates a serialized result document with the XHTML markup.

A second stylesheet could then process the result document of the first stylesheet e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:html" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

But you can't do it within one stylesheet with a result tree fragment as *doe* (disable-output-escaping) is a serialization feature and if you work with result tree fragments converted to a node set with the help of `exsl:node-set` or similar within one stylesheet there is no serialization happening.

Looking closer, as your snippet seems to contain references to undeclared entities like `&middot;` I think the sample does not parse as XML at all so you would need to fix that first to do any XSLT processing.